# iphone - Can self.view transitions be animated?

Tags: iphone, animation, view, switch-statement

The code below is from another SO post, and my question is can the transition from one view to the next using this method be animated, and if so how?

```
// origView is an instance variable/IBOutlet to your original view.
- (IBAction)switchToPhoneView:(id)sender {
  if (origView == nil)
    origView = self.view;
  self.view = phoneViewController.view;
}

- (IBAction)switchToOriginalView:(id)sender {
  self.view = origView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [this Apple example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/ViewTransitions/index.html) might be what you're looking for.